# JQuery Ajax call error in ASP.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using jquery ajax call in asp.net,I have a static web method with some parameters, When I am trying to debug its not hitting the method, I saw in error log its showing parseError, I removed all parameters and checked,but still same error,

```
[WebMethod]
  private static void AddData(int type, int categ, string desc, string date, string city, string state)

        {
//Do Processing
        }
```

I also tried with this,but same error

```
[WebMethod]
        private static void AddData()
        {
//do Processing
        }
```

This is my ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
              url: 'MyPage.aspx/AddData?type=' + encodeURIComponent(crimetype) + "&categ=" + encodeURIComponent(crimecateg) + "&desc=" + encodeURIComponent(desc) + "&date=" + encodeURIComponent(crimedate) + "&city=" + encodeURI(city) + "&state=" + encodeURIComponent(stateid),

                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                },
                error: function (data, errorThrown) {
                    debugger
                    alert(errorThrown);
                    alert(data.toString());
                }
            });
```

I tried with this as well

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'MyPage.aspx/AddData',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                },
                error: function (data, errorThrown) {
                    debugger
                    alert(errorThrown);
                    alert(data.toString());
                }
            });
```

All parameters are passing correctly

Comment: does putting the URL in **" "** instead of **' '** change anything?

Answer (score 1):

Change the Access Modifier

```
private static void AddData()
```

to

```
public static void AddData()
```

Comment: its not hitting when I am debugging the method

Comment: u mean the c# method? And where r u calling the ajax call?

Comment: yes its C# web method and I am calling it in asp.net page

Comment: i mean where r u calling the ajax call..in document ready or on click of some button.Can u show dat code

Comment: its in a function whhich is outside document.ready, and I am calling it inside document.ready

Answer (score 0):

All parameters going to json data like so:

```
var jsonData = {
    categ: value,
    desc: value,
    // and others
}

$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'MyPage.aspx/AddData'
                data: jsonData //your parameters
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                },
                error: function (data, errorThrown) {
                    debugger
                    alert(errorThrown);
                    alert(data.toString());
                }
            });
```

Comment: Could you elaborate this answer? What changes did you make and what are the effects?

Comment: its not hitting the method when I am debugging the method

Comment: you forget data property in $.ajax function, this property is include all ur url parameters

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
[WebMethod]
public static void AddData()
{
   //Your logic
}
```

And during call

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            InsertData();
        });
        function InsertData() {
            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",

                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                url: "MyPage.aspx/AddData",

                data: "{}",

                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {}
                error: function (data, errorThrown) {
                    debugger
                    alert(errorThrown);
                    alert(data.toString());
                }
            });
```